# How can I initialization String array set null in java?

Tags: java, null, initialization

Title is all.
How can I initialization String array set null in Java?
for example,

```
String[] arr; 
arr = sqlite.select(1);
//here I want to set null arr!
```

Comment: `arr = null;` ? What do you mean by _"I want to set null arr"_ ?

Comment: Please could you make an effort to write a correct sentence? This is very hard to understand what you are saying.

Comment: I understand English might not be your first language, but what you're saying doesn't make sense. For a `String[]` to have no values, you would initialize it as `new String[0]`. If you want the `String` array to contain elements, but all those elements are referencing `null`, then you need to access each element and set its value to `null`.

Comment: umm.. I want String array arr has no values. Initialization it! Like, if code executed line number 2, it will set arr[0] = "myid" arr[1] = "otherId" arr[2] = "msg" and I want arr set arr[0] = null arr[1] = null arr[2] = null in line number 3

Comment: umm.. If you want the `String` array to contain elements, but all those elements are referencing `null`, then you need to access each element and set its value to `null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you want array like

```
String[] arr = {"foo", "bar"};
```

to become

```
[null, null]
```

and do it in one line, then you can use

```
Arrays.fill(arr, null);
```

or create new array with same size as previous one

```
arr = new String[arr.length];
```